# how to select database name of same server using condition

Tags: sql

i  have 4 database ( dec2020,nov2020,oct2020,jan2021) that contain same tables.like dec2020 contain only dec data and jan contain only jan data.. i want create a report  based on from and to date(eg from date dec2020 to date jan2021).how  will i choose database dynamically depending on month..

Comment: You don't.  Instead, you fix your data model so similar data is stored in a *single* table, with a column specifying the month.

Comment: If you had a single database with all the data, the solution would be trivial.

Comment: no i can't.. ram gets full if we maintain single database..

Comment: You should look into changing your model, but if you cannot do that you can look up Dynamic SQL. You will need to write parametrizable queries that will be generated dynamically based on input at runtime.

Comment: Which DBMS product are you using? "SQL" is just a query language used by all relational databases, not the name of a specific database product. Please add a [tag](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging) for the database product you are using. [Why should I tag my DBMS](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/)

Answer (score 0):

The datamodel you have is strange however you should be able to do something like the below. It is not best practice however:

Bear in mind I don't know what your data looks like.

```
declare @AllData table
(
Customer nvarchar(25),
Sold decimal (19,2),
Date datetime
)

insert into @AllData 

select [Customer], [sold], [date]] from Jan.dbo.YourTable

union all

 select [customer], [sold] [date] from Dec.dbo.YourTable




 select * from @AllData

 where date between 'bla' and 'bla'
```

Comment: temprary table stored in ram .. so the ram will be full..

Comment: Then it may be worthwhile to address the issue of the server running out of RAM.